# How can I extend a resource in HAPI FHIR JPA Server?

Tags: java, jpa, hl7-fhir, hapi

I'm trying to extend the standard resource `Appointment` to include the organization responsible for it.

I followed the [docu](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/model/custom_structures.html) and the explanation of the [ResourceDef](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/model/api/annotation/ResourceDef.java) annotation that suggests the following is correct.

```java
@ResourceDef
public class TeamedioAppointment extends Appointment {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Child(name = "organizer")
  @Extension(url="https://teamedio.de/fhir/actor-role#Organizer", definedLocally=false, isModifier=false)
  @Description(shortDefinition = "The organization responsible for the appointment")
  private StringType organizer;

  public StringType getOrganizer() {
    if (organizer == null) {
      organizer = new StringType();
    }
    return organizer;
 }

  public void setOrganizer(StringType orgRef) {
    organizer = orgRef;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
     return super.isEmpty() && ElementUtil.isEmpty(organizer);
  }
}
```

Now my expectation is that it will override the `Appointment` resource and use the one I provided (as it has the same name).  But that's not what is happening.

If I `POST` an Appointment resource I get just the Standard Appointment from the `RequestDetails` object.

I guess I have to register it also somewhere?
I already tried to add it to the context, but didn't help either:

```java
protected void initialize() throws ServletException {
  //...
  getFhirContext().registerCustomType(TeamedioAppointment.class);
}
```

Comment: If you want to be conformant, you need to use the extension element, not define your own.  Also, the organization associated with the appointment is typically conveyed by the organization of the participants.  (The model allows for the possibility that an appointment may involve resources from multiple organizations.)

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie exactly that's why we want to model an organization as taking responsability over the appointment in a collegial appointment. In my Question I'm trying to use the extension, not generating a new resource hence no name in `@ ResourceDef `. The FHIR Model is correct and not the issue, the problem is that the HAPI JPA server is not using it when getting an Appointment resource. My intention is to work transparently with the Java Object which only defines the extension.